# Android Studio Emulator: Process finished with exit code 3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-studio-3.0

I'm trying to use android studio for the first time on my new laptop, but I'm having trouble getting the emulator to run so I can test my apps. I have an AMD CPU which I am aware causes difficulties with the emulator, but the image I have installed should work with my CPU: it is Android 7.1.1 with Google API's and the CPU/ABI is ARM, so theoretically it should work fine. However, when I run the emulator, the nexus devices shows up and then closes, and the log displays this error: 
1:00 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

1:00 PM * daemon started successfully

1:00 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

1:00 PM Emulator: **

1:00 PM Emulator: ERROR:/buildbot/src/android/emu-3.0-release/external/qemu/fpu/softfloat.c:486:round_canonical: code should not be reached

1:00 PM Emulator: Warning: QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread ((null):0, (null))

1:00 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 3

I have no idea what this means and no idea how to fix it. I tried restarting android studio, I don't know what else I could do to fix the issue. Anyone have any ideas?